# Correct denotation for sum function

Tags: summation, notation

The variable $x(t)$ can assume the values 0 or 1 at every time-slot (minute) $t$. The sum of all $x$ over the course of one week has to be at least 25 (every week! meaning there can never be a 7 day period without at least 25).

I formulated this as follows:
$$\sum_{t}^{t+7~days}x(t) \geq 25$$ Someone (no mathematician) indicated that the correct form for this might be:
$$\sum\nolimits_{t=i}^{i+7~days}x(t) \geq 25$$

Is this correct? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: In the second form you have $t=i$ where $i$ is not known.

Comment: The variable $t$ must range from $1$ (the first time-slot) up to .... the last time-slot.

Comment: Since the condition must be met for every $i$, would adding $ i \in \mathbb{Z}$ behind the second form be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We could write
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{t=i}^{i+7\cdot24\cdot 60-1}x(t)\geq 25\qquad i\in\mathbb{Z},\ i\geq 0
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering: is the transformation of $7~days$ to $7\cdot 24\cdot 60$ solely done so that the $-1$ does not have to be specified as $-1~min$?

Comment: @cheesus: I'ts just to prevent overcounting. For instance to count the minutes within an hour you could write $\sum_{t=0}^{59}1=60$. You see? We don't use the unit *minute* within the calculation.